# Как из JSON файла получить все значения Python

Tags: python, json, парсер, list, for

такая проблема, учусь парсить сайты, получил JSON файл с нужными мне данными, требуется получить все значения ключа "день_недели", "дисциплина". Дело в том, что данные лежат списком а не словарем и через `for` выбрать не получается. Как мне преобразовать такой список в словарь? Или же можно получить значения другим методом. Ниже пример json со списком

```
[
{
    "код": 3390870,
    "дата": "2022-11-21T00:00:00",
    "начало": "08:30",
    "датаНачала": "2022-11-21T08:30:00",
    "датаОкончания": "2022-11-21T10:05:00",
    "конец": "10:05",
    "деньНедели": 1,
    "день_недели": "Понедельник",
    "почта": "",
    "день": "1 Понедельник",
    "код_Семестра": 1,
    "типНедели": 13,
    "номерПодгруппы": 0,
    "дисциплина": "лек История",
    "преподаватель": "Бычкова М.В.",
    "должность": "Препод.",
    "аудитория": "201",
    "учебныйГод": "2022-2023",
    "группа": "560 фк-2",
    "custom1": "Бычкова М.В.\n201",
    "часы": "08:30\n10:05",
    "неделяНачала": -100,
    "неделяОкончания": -100,
    "замена": false,
    "кодПреподавателя": 72,
    "кодГруппы": 2927,
    "фиоПреподавателя": "Бычкова М.В.",
    "кодПользователя": 1182,
    "элементЦиклРасписания": false,
    "тема": " ",
    "номерЗанятия": 1,
    "ссылка": null,
    "созданиеВебинара": false,
    "кодВебинара": null,
    "вебинарЗапущен": false,
    "кодыСтрок": [
        3390870
    ]
},
{
    "код": 3390871,
    "дата": "2022-11-21T00:00:00",
    "начало": "10:15",
    "датаНачала": "2022-11-21T10:15:00",
    "датаОкончания": "2022-11-21T11:50:00",
    "конец": "11:50",
    "деньНедели": 1,
    "день_недели": "Понедельник",
    "почта": "",
    "день": "1 Понедельник",
    "код_Семестра": 1,
    "типНедели": 13,
    "номерПодгруппы": 0,
    "дисциплина": "лек Основы философии",
    "преподаватель": "Шубина Ю.Н.",
    "должность": "Препод.",
    "аудитория": "114",
    "учебныйГод": "2022-2023",
    "группа": "560 фк-2",
    "custom1": "Шубина Ю.Н.\n114",
    "часы": "10:15\n11:50",
    "неделяНачала": -100,
    "неделяОкончания": -100,
    "замена": false,
    "кодПреподавателя": 1242,
    "кодГруппы": 2927,
    "фиоПреподавателя": "Шубина Ю.Н.",
    "кодПользователя": 1429,
    "элементЦиклРасписания": false,
    "тема": " ",
    "номерЗанятия": 2,
    "ссылка": null,
    "созданиеВебинара": false,
    "кодВебинара": null,
    "вебинарЗапущен": false,
    "кодыСтрок": [
        3390871
    ]
},
```

....

Main код:

```
    import requests
import json


# Take data
def get_data():
    cookies = {
        '_ym_d': '1662050588',
        '_ym_uid': '1662050588532803136',
        'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'm1tpedtggmo3ondbwe0weyxa',
        '__AntiXsrfToken': '5675b54e6a12462ca7f04cfb7832ba7b',
        'authToken': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoidmlzaWdyaXpsaUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9zdXJuYW1lIjoi0J_QtdGF0L7QsiDQnC7QkC4iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9oYXNoIjoiMTExMDIwMjExMjAzIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvc2lkIjoiLTIxMDEzIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy91c2VyZGF0YSI6IjIiLCJ2ZXJpZlN0cmluZyI6IiIsIm5iZiI6MTY2ODQ0Nzg2MSwiZXhwIjoxNjY5MDUyNjYxLCJpc3MiOiJWZWRLYWYiLCJhdWQiOiJNTUlTTGFiIn0.8jdWkTLrpUE2qPfvR6rCJt9VGNmMB1188Vi-zhQ7J7c',
    }

    headers = {
        'authority': 'edu-tpi.donstu.ru',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoidmlzaWdyaXpsaUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9zdXJuYW1lIjoi0J_QtdGF0L7QsiDQnC7QkC4iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9oYXNoIjoiMTExMDIwMjExMjAzIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvc2lkIjoiLTIxMDEzIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy91c2VyZGF0YSI6IjIiLCJ2ZXJpZlN0cmluZyI6IiIsIm5iZiI6MTY2ODQ0Nzg2MSwiZXhwIjoxNjY5MDUyNjYxLCJpc3MiOiJWZWRLYWYiLCJhdWQiOiJNTUlTTGFiIn0.8jdWkTLrpUE2qPfvR6rCJt9VGNmMB1188Vi-zhQ7J7c',
        'client-version': '2022-10-23T16:36:04.766Z',
        # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
        # 'cookie': '_ym_d=1662050588; _ym_uid=1662050588532803136; ASP.NET_SessionId=m1tpedtggmo3ondbwe0weyxa; __AntiXsrfToken=5675b54e6a12462ca7f04cfb7832ba7b; authToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoidmlzaWdyaXpsaUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9zdXJuYW1lIjoi0J_QtdGF0L7QsiDQnC7QkC4iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9oYXNoIjoiMTExMDIwMjExMjAzIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvc2lkIjoiLTIxMDEzIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy91c2VyZGF0YSI6IjIiLCJ2ZXJpZlN0cmluZyI6IiIsIm5iZiI6MTY2ODQ0Nzg2MSwiZXhwIjoxNjY5MDUyNjYxLCJpc3MiOiJWZWRLYWYiLCJhdWQiOiJNTUlTTGFiIn0.8jdWkTLrpUE2qPfvR6rCJt9VGNmMB1188Vi-zhQ7J7c',
        'referer': 'https://edu-tpi.donstu.ru/WebApp/',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="106", "Not.A/Brand";v="24", "Opera GX";v="92"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/92.0.0.0',
    }

    params = {
        'idGroup': '2927',
        'sdate': '2022-11-21',
    }

    response = requests.get('https://edu-tpi.donstu.ru/api/Rasp', params=params, cookies=cookies,
                            headers=headers).json()

    ordinary = response.get('data').get('rasp')

    with open('1_rasp.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(ordinary, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

    ordinary_list = {}

    for ordinary_info in ordinary:
        day = ordinary_info.get('деньНедели')
        disc = ordinary_info.get('дисциплина')
        teacher = ordinary_info.get('преподаватель')
        aud = ordinary_info.get('аудитория')

        ordinary_list[day] = {
            'Дисциплина: ': disc,
            'Преподаватель: ': teacher,
            'Аудитория: ': aud,
        }
    with open('2_ordinary_info.json', "w") as file:
        json.dump(ordinary_list, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data()
```

Comment: а можно увидеть ваш код "через for выбрать не получается"?

Comment: да, сейчас добавлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Занеси значения list в любую переменную(Пример: a = [{'_id': 1, '_id: 2'}, {'_id:': 3, '_id': 4}]) )

После, чтобы получить данные, находящиеся в ключе напишем:

```
n1 = [] ## любая переменная, где ты хочешь хранить результаты

for i in range(len(a)): ## где а - наш список
    n1.append(a[i]['день_недели'])
    n1.append(a[i]['дисциплина'])
```

Теперь все всё находится в списке n1.
Надеюсь, я правильно понял твою проблему)

Comment: Вооу, дааа, именно то что мне нужно было, большое спасибо Вам за помощь, прям выручили) Уже 3й день ищу решения, так и ничего не придумал и не нашел)

Comment: Рад был помочь вам!

Answer (score 1):

У вас в цикле ключи перезаписываются(можете посмотреть в дебагере).
Ключи для словаря должны быть уникальными на пример:

```
for ordinary_info in ordinary:
    day = ordinary_info.get('деньНедели')
    lesson = ordinary_info.get('номерЗанятия')
    disc = ordinary_info.get('дисциплина')
    teacher = ordinary_info.get('преподаватель')
    aud = ordinary_info.get('аудитория')

ordinary_list[f'{day}_{lesson}'] = {
    'Дисциплина: ': disc,
    'Преподаватель: ': teacher,
    'Аудитория: ': aud,
}
```